# Problem About Norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Show: If $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $\|A\|_F\leq1$, then prove that $I-A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: I have no ideas.

Comment: This is very much a "proof of work" site, you need to show some effort or attempt.

Comment: OK,this is the first time I use this site.

Comment: Can you also define what $F$ is?

Comment: it's A‘s Frobenius norm.

Comment: There's a relation between Frobenuis norm and sum of squares of singular values which for symmetrical matrix are also eigenvalues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A\in M_n$ is symmetric, there exist an orthogonal matrix $U\in M_n$ such that $U^T AU=\mathrm{diag}(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. Also note that $\|A\|_F=\|U^TAU\|_F$.
So $a_i\leq 1$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Therefore, $U^T(I-A)U= I-U^TAU= \mathrm{diag}(1-a_1, \ldots, 1-a_n)$ is positive semidefinite and so $I-A$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: does it use the property of similar matrices in the last sentence?

Comment: Yes.  A is positive if and only if U^*AU is positive.